# Single word to describe a person who is difficult to work with

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe someone who is difficult to work with in a work environment.  They turn down offers to help but then blame you if things aren't done, try to actively go against what you say in group settings, and do not take your advice or listen (even if you know more about the subject or have been working on a project longer).

Comment: If no answers meaning 'difficult to work with' rather than just 'difficult to be / live with' appear in the near future, I will close-vote as the answers are too general.

Comment: I think the difficulty is finding a *single* word when there are so many to choose from

Comment: They're called Managers aren't they?

Comment: @Avon In I.T. these type of managers are called Manglement

Comment: @Dijkgraaf That's a good word. So, Manglers should be the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) no sign of research is shown; (2) the question is generating mere synonyms for 'difficult' [personality sense].

Comment: The question does not show much research, so I have voted to close it too. Better research might have dissuaded the low quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a single word that means all of those things and applies only to workplace interactions, but there are a couple of words that are close because they exclude standard relationships between adult friends or acquaintances.

**Insubordinate** requires some authority, so it implies a hierarchy and thus can't apply to typical interpersonal relationships and is probably the closest to what you describe, but also means that they are undermining someone above them rather than an equal.

**Recalcitrant** has some connotations of work, authority, and spitefulness and requires you to be attempting to accomplish something, otherwise there is nothing to resist. It would also be applied to a stubborn child or animal, but would not make sense to use between friends or acquaintances.

Comment: **Intractable** is also pretty good.

Comment: **Recalcitrant** is the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

**Backbiter?**

This is someone who tries to hurt your reputation behind your back, often (but admittedly not always) in a workplace setting.

Answer (score 0):

***Insecure*** is probably accurate, but that's getting a little more meta than you probably mean.

Comment: This is not limited to 'difficult to _work_ with'.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***non-collaborative***?

Seems to be apt for workplace difficulty.

Comment: Getting better, but this could mean not collaborating rather than being perverse.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'm curious, do you suspect that there might be no single term which meets all the requirements of the question?

Comment: Yes, I do (though someone may prove me wrong). (And part of me wonders why such a detailed character-assassination is being spelled out.)

Comment: I hear what you're saying.